# Why mongodb count without condition less than count with condition?

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('cos_mid').find().count() - db.getCollection('cos_mid').find({detail:{$exists:true}}).count()
```

give me

[image]

Why count without condition is less than count with condition ? How can I find these 41 docs ? The doc is not changed by other processes, I run a lot of time, everytime return `-41`.

**EDIT**

Here is a stats.

[image]

Comment: Is your db sharded and chunk migration is currently running?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, it's a standalone server.

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you running? One suggestion: try running `db.cos_mid.validate()`. Count statistics for the "fast count" in WiredTiger (`count()` without a query predicate) may [drift after an unclean shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#accuracy-after-unexpected-shutdown).

Comment: @Stennie Thanks, after running `db.cos_mid.validate({full:true})`, it's `0` now.